# WiX: No shortcut is created for common component

Tags: wix

I have 2 features (feature1 and feature2)
both of them uses comon componentgroup like this:

```
<Feature1 ...
<ComponentGroupRef Id="compA">
>
```

And the same:

```
<Feature2 ...
<ComponentGroupRef Id="compA">
>
```

CompA:

```
<Component Id="ComponentA">
<Shortcut Id="ImportantShortcurt" Advertise="yes" Directory="..."
        Name="..." LongName="..." Icon="..."/>
</Component>
```

This component is included in

```
<ComponentGroup Id="compA">
    <ComponentRef Id="ComponentA" />   
    ....
</ComponentGroup>
```

User can choose to install Feature1, Feature2, both of them.
If he chooses to install both or Feature2 - everything is OK, if only Feature1, but not Feature2 - everything is OK except there is no shortcut with Id "ImportantShortcut" (files are installed, only shortcut is absent).

I was using msiexec with logging. Everything seems to be OK, but

> Executing op: ShortcutCreate for my shortcut is absent

Feature1 is in file1.wxi, Feature2 is in file2.wxi
Both of them are included in product file.

```
<Fragment ...>
<?Include file1.wxi>
<?Include file2.wxi>
<...>
```

So, a question: where is shortcut if Feature2 is absent? All files from ComponentA are here.

Comment: I can add any part of log-file. It is over 3M, so I can attach parts, connected with Feature1, Feature2, ComponentA, shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is interesting. My first reaction would be probably that the Feature2 pulls "shortcut" for himself, even if the feature2 is disabled or not.

For starters, I would implement shortcut correctly, eg using RemoveFolder & adding registry key for marking it as keyPath, like here:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html

See if that makes it better, I am not that familiar with Advertise flag, it might affect.

Alternatively, just use ORCA.EXE and see what is going on with the tables. You will understand this way a lot better. You can use ORCA.exe to compare two .MSI files and see which part does the tricks - then we can look further, if you didn't find a fix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Orca has showed, that my shortcut is the only target of my Feature2, so result is here: no Feature2 - no shortcut. But I don't know, how to do it: shortcut must be here if feature1 or feature2 is installed (or both of them). Sorry, I am a noob in WiX. It is difficult for me to learn something after C/C++ :)

Comment: May be I should add component as an independent feature? I am still learning WiX, but I will go on with my experiments.

Comment: Yes, that is the easiest one. I don't have code right now, but you can create new feature, put your shortcut there and make the feature "ENABLED ALWAYS". By the way, you can use component/feature logic, so your feature will be installed only if feature1 or feature2 is present.